# DataTrigger not binding in Style

Tags: wpf

I am having trouble using a data trigger in my Style.

I want to switch on the `HasImage` property of my `SelectedLocationInPage`. As a simple test that I can read the property, this is working:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding ExamManager}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LocationViewModel}">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource imageLocationButton}">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>

            <DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="20">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedLocationInPage}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HasImage}" FontSize="100"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The upper content control displays a grid of cells (an exam) and when you select a cell that cell should display in the lower content control. As written above, selecting between a cell with or without an image (`HasImage == true/false`) correctly displays "True" or "False" in the lower content control.

So I take the next step and try to render a different content template depending on the value of `HasImage`, and I can't get it to work. When I use the code below, the view just shows the default string representation (i.e., the fully qualified type of `SelectedLocationInPage`).

(I've also tried binding to `DataContext.HasImage` to no avail. Also, I know I technically don't need to handle true and false -- I could/should have one default and one trigger -- but I want to make sure everything I'm trying is on the same level to avoid any confusion as I figure this out)

```xml
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedLocationInPage}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasImage}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="HAS IMAGE" FontSize="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasImage}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="NO IMAGE" FontSize="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

I'm not sure if there's any other code that would help (viewmodels etc), I believe all you need to know is that `HasImage` is a bool property of the `SelectedImageInPage`, and that in the first example the `HasImage` property works no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the binding in the second code snippit should be:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocationInPage.HasImage}">
```

`{Binding HasImage}` works inside the `DataTemplate` because the `DataContext` automatically changes to the value of `ContentControl.Content`, but these `DataTrigger`s are defined *outside* of the `DataTemplate` at the `ContentControl` level, so they use the same `DataContext` as `Content="{Binding SelectedLocationInPage}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Binding directly to `HasImage` only works in the `ContentTemplate` of the `ContentControl` provided that the current `Content` has an `HasImage` property.

The `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` itself, to which the `Style` is being applied, has no `HasImage` property.

Try to bind to `Content.HasImage`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.HasImage}" FontSize="100"/>
```